# Laravel: auth()->attempt undefined method

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-blade

Everything seems to work, but VSCODE keeps reporting an error on attempt. Saying that the method has not been defined.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validation
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|max:50',
            'username' => 'required|max:50',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:250',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
        ]);
        //create new user
        User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'username' => $request->username,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password'));

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

        //sign the user in
        //redirect
    }
}
```

is it a vscode problem or am I missing something?

Comment: Try this  auth('users')->attempt($request->only('email','password'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is I solved:

Open the extension settings:

[image]

And open json of setting

[image]

The variables you should consider are:

```sh
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedTypes": false,
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedFunctions": false,
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedConstants": false,
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedClassConstants": false,
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedMethods": false,
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedProperties": false,
"intelephense.diagnostics.undefinedVariables": false,
```

then press `control + shift+p` and search for `intelephense` then select `index worksapce`

Comment: Note that this suppresses the error, but Intelephense will not suggest the `attempt` method. My solution suppresses the error and also allows the extension to suggest the method, but it too is not without a caveat. You code base change will be lost, when you update the framework via composer.

Comment: Suppressing the undef methods seems to be more unhelpful of a solution. Because now intellisense won't alert methods that actually don't exist and thus cause errors. [Github resolve issue](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/2039#issuecomment-987241746) either asks to install another helper plugin or cast the auth::user type

Answer (score 7):

So I think I followed the same [tutorial of TraversyMedia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFh0Fd7BsjE&t=5609s)'s guest Alex, and stumbled upon the very same problem.

While suppressing diagnostics obviously work, it's not quite what I want (would not accept).

In this case the method `attempt` exists, so I just want the awesome Intelephense extension to recognize it.

I'll try to explain so it's applicable to more than just this case.

## Solution

`Ctrl + click` on `auth()` which is supposed to have the method brings us to `helpers.php` file where the function is defined.

There we see a small bit of code with an `if` statement, but either way it returns the same class, namely `AuthFactory`.

So again we `Ctrl + click` on `AuthFactory` and we find ourselves staring at `Factory` interface namespaced `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth`;

Now we can use PHPDocs to tell Intelephense that a method named `attempt` can be used on an instance of this interface. Note the "comment" (PHPDocs) just above `interface Factory` declaration in the full code below.

```php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Contracts\Auth;

/**
 * @method attempt
 */
interface Factory
{
    /**
     * Get a guard instance by name.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $name
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard|\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    public function guard($name = null);

    /**
     * Set the default guard the factory should serve.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return void
     */
    public function shouldUse($name);
}
```

Voilà !

### Note

You should only do this if the method really does exist, otherwise you're nailing your own coffin.